# modify gzipped file with python

Tags: python, io, gzip

I am trying to modify the gzipped file.
Here is my code:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, tmp)
    # do smth here later
    with gzip.open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(tmp, f)
```

I removed all modifications, only left the read and write. On output I get the empty gzipped file. What's wrong with this? (Python 2.7.6, Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to the beginning of the temporary file after copy:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, tmp)
        tmp.seek(0)
```

Comment: right. stupid me. will accept it later, have to run now